# How to make rotatable 3D Cube with UIView on each side

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos3d

I would like to implement something like this cube menu: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swiss/id343038584?mt=8

I want to add UIView on each side of the cube and to rotate only by x axis.

Any good example from where I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel

You can customize it!

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much.